# How to sort Enums by Counting Sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, enums

For example, I want to sort Enum. And I have an object with key as `Enum`

**UPDATED**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Bean[] mass = new Bean[] { new Bean(new Object(), A), new Bean(new Object(), C), new Bean(new Object(), D),
                new Bean(new Object(), B), new Bean(new Object(), A) }; // 1, 3, 4, 2, 1
        Arrays.sort(mass, new EnumComparator());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mass)); //[1, 1, 2, 3, 4]

    }
}

class EnumComparator implements Comparator<Bean> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Bean o1, Bean o2) {
        return o1.key.toString().compareTo(o2.key.toString());
    }

}

class Bean {
    public Object data;
    public Enum key;

    public Bean(Object data, Enum key) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return key.toString();
    }

}

enum MyEnum {

    D("4"),
    A("1"),
    B("2"),
    C("3");

    private String index;

    private MyEnum(String index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return index;
    }

}
```

Sorting `Arrays.sort` uses `TimSort` or `MergeSort` to run on average `O (n log n)`. But if we use a finite number of constants (`Enums`), we can use the [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) in time `O (n)`. Is there a standard mechanism for using counting sort for `Enums` in `java`?

Comment: You always can use some other utility method instead of `Arrays.sort()` or write one yourself, but with only a few elements, does it really matter? The difference in performance would be almost negligible. And that doesn't even say a counting sort would actually be better for enums.

Comment: i would rather ask the question, if for a finite set of enums it makes a difference to sort in `O(n)`or in `O(n log n)`. While being for an asymptotic analysis irrelevant, constants can get very interesting for running code

Comment: I have an array of objects in which `Enum` acts as the key and I need to sort through.

Comment: There isn't a standard mechanism for counting sort in Java, period. Although it is a fairly trivial algorithm to write oneself, and you can probably find endless examples of this online.

Comment: I do not agree with you. If there is an object in which Enum acts as the key and it is necessary to sort an array with such objects, it will be necessary to remember the number of identical objects and fill the new array from the necessary index, it is not so trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the order of the constants in advance you can use a `HashMap` to implement a counting sort:

```
List<MyEnum> countingSort(MyEnum order[], List<MyEnum> input) {
    HashMap<MyEnum, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (MyEnum obj : input) {
        countMap.put(obj, countMap.getOrDefault(obj, 0) + 1);
    }

    List<MyEnum> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MyEnum obj : order) {
        for (int i = 0; i < countMap.getOrDefault(obj, 0); ++i) {
            result.add(obj);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {   
    MyEnum order[] = {A, B, C, D};
    List<MyEnum> input = Arrays.asList(D, C, A, B, D, D, B, A, A, C, D);
    List<MyEnum> res = countingSort(order, input);
}
```

The complexity of this approach is `O(n)` in average.

---

In the updated version of the question, you are asking about [pigeonhole sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort). It is similar to counting sort but has its own name. We need several changes in the algorithm above. First, we need to replace a `HashMap<MyEnum, Integer>` with `HashMap<MyEnum, List<Bean>>`, and store all `Bean` objects in the corresponding lists. Then after iteration through the input, we need to join all that lists in the specified order.

Comment: Yes everything is correct. But in your solution we fill the list with identical objects instead of real ones). Imagine a situation where a composite object contains an `Enum` as a key field, and we need all the rest of the information.

Comment: For example `objA{MyEnum enum = MyEnum.A, public Integer index = **1**)` and `objB{MyEnum enum = MyEnum.A, public Integer index = **2**)`. I think it return the first one for every call. In other implementations an array of diapozones with the same objects is created and for the next pass is filled with the necessary values. First loop = counting diapozones, second loop = fill the array.

Answer (score 0):

A distinct *non* answer here: don't.

Do not worry about O(n) vs O(n*log(n)). Worry about writing human readable code that can be maintained and enhanced over time.

There are two cases:

- *n* is so large that the difference matters. This means that *n* is probably a **really** large number. Then you are facing a *truck load* of other, more important aspects you should first focus on. Because then *each and any* step in your "processing chain" matters. In such cases, you have to carefully look at each step, and determine how to optimize it (and most likely, you have to do **measurements** prior being able to apply optimizations that make a difference)
- *n* is so small that ... uups: *n* is small. Meaning we are talking about "less than milli seconds" in the first place.

Long story short: this sounds like a typical pre-mature optimisation. And then the only valid answer is: focus on writing clean, elegant code that gets the job done. Then *measure* with real data. And then decide if further action is required (and most of times: it is not).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no discussing about should we use `O(n)` or `O(nlogn)` is enough. Anyway, probably you could implement custom `counting sort` algorithm? (I do not remember that any lib I know have this):

```
private static void countSort(Bean[] mass) {
    List<Bean>[] arr = (List<Bean>[])new List[MyEnum.values().length];

    for (Bean bean : mass) {
        int pos = Integer.parseInt(bean.key.getIndex()) - 1;

        if (arr[pos] == null)
            arr[pos] = new ArrayList<>();

        arr[pos].add(bean);
    }

    int i = 0;

    for (List<Bean> beans : arr)
        for (Bean bean : beans)
            mass[i++] = bean;
}
```